# Coercing different values to be equal based on another column's value

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I know the title may be confusing and it may be hard for me to explain. I would like to take a data frame with repetitious values in the first column and change values in a different column to be the same for the repetitious values in the first column. So then I can call the unique() to reduce the table down.

For example:

```
rawdata<- data.frame(User=c('JSmith','JSmith','JDoe','JDoe','MDog','MDog','MDog') ,
                       Visit=c('Y','N','N','N','Y','N','Y'))
#displayed as  
   User    Visit
1 JSmith     Y
2 JSmith     N
3   JDoe     N
4   JDoe     N
5   MDog     Y
6   MDog     N
7   MDog     Y

#I would like to test the visit column for Y and if that is true for user's of the same name, 
#coerce that visit value to Y as well

 User    Visit
1 JSmith     Y
2 JSmith     Y
3   JDoe     N
4   JDoe     N
5   MDog     Y
6   MDog     Y
7   MDog     Y

#That way when I call unique(rawdata[,1]), it should output
 User    Visit
1 JSmith     Y
2   JDoe     N
3   MDog     Y
```

I used this simplified example for me to apply the principle to a much larger and more complicated data set, but the principle is the same. Unfortunately I don't know where to start. I was thinking a for loop with if statements but I'm not sure how to coerce the 2nd column values for all values in the first column that are equal. Any suggestions on how to tackle this. Thank you!

Comment: In my actual dataset there are 4 values: B, M, P, and N. I was going to piece your code to do: if any B all B, if M & P all B, if P all P, if M all M. Using those statements in order I would be able to get all values into B, M, P, and N to use the distinct(). Therefore, I have to be careful with else statements to not coerce the important values to N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'User', `if` there are any 'Y', then change 'Visit' to 'Y' and then get the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
rawdata %>% 
    group_by(User) %>% 
    mutate(Visit = if('Y' %in% Visit) 'Y' else 'N') %>%
    ungroup %>%
    distinct
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  User   Visit
#  <fct>  <chr>
#1 JSmith Y    
#2 JDoe   N    
#3 MDog   Y
```

If we need only the intermediate output,  then the `group_by/mutate` in the previous step is only needed

---

Or another option is to `summarise` after doing a group by

```
rawdata %>%
   group_by(User) %>% 
   summarise(Visit = Visit[match('Y', Visit, nomatch = 1)])
```

---

Or we could `arrange` the dataset and then do a `distinct`

```
rawdata %>%
    arrange(User, Visit == 'N') %>% 
    distinct(User, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I believe the first set of code would work for my complicated data set, but I have this error.
```
Error: incompatible types (NULL), expecting character
```
I had to leave off the else statement because my actual data set is more complicated and has 4 values in the 'visit' column and I don't want to wipe them all to N. I'm not sure where the source of this error is because both columns I'm working with are class character.

Comment: Your answer did work for the data frame given. Thank you! I realize the error is something to do with my data set.

Comment: @MDoster it could be related to the dataset.  If you can dput the example with the error, it would be helpful

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide the specific data. The data is a government collected private dataset. The only things I guess I can provide is the data is in [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame" format and the class of column that I'm trying to manipulate is character.

Comment: @MDoster  You don't need to give the exact data.  I meant, you can change the values, column names etc, and get a small data with `dput(droplevels(head(rawdata, 30)))` and the expected output for that.  It is just to understand the structure and why it is failing.  Can you check the `str(rawdata)` to find the class of each of the columns used in this solution

Comment: `dput(droplevels(head(rawdata))) outputs:
structure(list(SeriesID = c("ACD1101001", "ACD1101001", "ACD1101001", 
"ACD1101001", "ACD1101001", "ACD1101001"), Predators = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
`

Comment: `str(rawdata) #outputs: Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 481870 obs. of 2 variables: $ SeriesID : chr "ACD1101001" "ACD1101001" "ACD1101001" "ACD1101001" ... ..- attr(, "label")= chr "SeriesID" ..- attr(, "format.sas")= chr "$" $ Predators: chr "" "" "" "" ... ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Predators" ..- attr(*, "format.sas")= chr "$" ` 
Predators is the column I refered to as 'Visit' and SeriesID is 'User'. There are blank values in the Predators column. And as you can see multiples of the same value in the Series ID column

Comment: @MDoster if di do `rawdata %>% 
     group_by(SeriesID) %>% mutate(Predators = if('Y' %in% Predators) 'Y' else 'N')  %>% ungroup %>% distinct` i am not getting any error

Comment: There's no error, but there's also no 'Y' in that column. The problem is that my data set is more complicated then if Y then N. I would need to include all these statements: if any B all B, if M & P all B, if P all P, if M all M, if "" all N.

Comment: @MDoster It is because you have only `""` there, here the condition is checking for 'Y' present . i.e. if it is present it would be 'Y' or else 'N'

Comment: @MDoster here is the output I get `rawdata %>% group_by(SeriesID) %>% mutate(Predators = if('Y' %in% Predators) 'Y' else 'N') %>% ungroup %>% distinct
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  SeriesID   Predators
  <chr>      <chr>    
1 ACD1101001 N`

Comment: Forget what I said before. I can totally apply your suggested code with as many if else statements as I need. Thank you so much for getting me to this point!!! However, it doesn't work for the part that I need to test the SeriesIDs for the presence of both 'M' and 'P', if that's true, change all values to 'B'. I tried:
`if('M' & 'P' %in% Predators) 'B' else` but I got this error: `Error in "M" & "P" %in% Predators : operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

Comment: @MDoster I think you need `all` `if(all(c("M", "P") %in% Predators)) "B" else ...`

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much for your time, wisdom, and patience!

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `ave` for each `User`.

```
rawdata$Visit <- with(rawdata, ave(Visit == 'Y', User, FUN = function(x) 
                               if(any(x)) 'Y' else 'N'))

rawdata
#    User Visit
#1 JSmith     Y
#2 JSmith     Y
#3   JDoe     N
#4   JDoe     N
#5   MDog     Y
#6   MDog     Y
#7   MDog     Y
```

Then you can take `unique` of data to get

```
unique(rawdata)

#    User Visit
#1 JSmith     Y
#3   JDoe     N
#5   MDog     Y
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I tried applying this code to my data set, I got this error. 
```
Error in x[i] <- value[[j]] : replacement has length zero.
```
I'm not 100% on what that means, but I did have to make an edit to the code. In my data set there are more than two values in the 'visit' column so I left out the else statement. That could be the source of the error not sure. Thank you for taking the time to answer me! This definitely gave me a start.

Comment: @MDoster Can you check what is `class(rawdata$Visit)` ?

Comment: The class of the column is character. The class of the data set is 
```
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```